# Как генерировать ссылку для авторизации через телеграм?

Tags: php, telegram, авторизация, redirect, oauth

Попробовал сформировать что то подобное

```
$params = [
  'bot_id'           => 'HIDE',
  'origin'           => 'HIDE',
  'embed'            => '1',
  'request_access'   => 'write',
  'return_to'        => 'HIDE',
];

$oauth_telegram = 'https://oauth.telegram.org/auth?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
```

но в результате при возвращение на `return_to` по мимо самого адреса к `URL` добавляется: `#tgAuthResult=eyJpZCI6MTAyMTkzODE0MiwiZmlyc3RfbmFtZSI6IkRhdmlkIiwibGFzdF9uYW1lIjoiTWV5c`

А мне на `return_to` нужно получать что то типо `JSON` массива:

```
array(7) { 
  ["id"]=> string(7) "1831337" 
  ["first_name"]=> string(18) "Александр" 
  ["last_name"]=> string(16) "Менщиков" 
  ["username"]=> string(5) "n0str" 
  ["photo_url"]=> string(36) "https://t.me/i/userpic/100/n0str.jpg" 
  ["auth_date"]=> string(10) "1518168109" 
  ["hash"]=> string(64) "abba<..>1345" 
}
```

Comment: чем теберабочий виджет авторизации не устраивает? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6516521b1fb3b464534fbc30ea3573c2

Comment: @Shilgen , не в вписывается в интерфейс сайта

Comment: В tgAuthResult лежит base64encoded json того вида что тебе надо

Comment: Меня больше интересует как hash провалидировать. Так как по ссылке выше не получается

Answer (score 0):

Если страница, на которую делается редирект, содержит тот же самый виджет аутентификации телеграмма, его скрипт ловит наличие `tgAuthResult` в адресе, разбирает значение из него и редиректит эту страницу ещё раз на саму себя, заменяя в адресе закладку с параметром `tgAuthResult` на нормальные get- аргументы в URL, соответствующие [доке](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login#checking-authorization) и [примеру](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6516521b1fb3b464534fbc30ea3573c2) из неё.

Если не содержит - вы можете сами раскодировать его base64encoded-значение, получить простой JSON с полями, один в один соответствующими расписанным в доке аргументам, декодировать их значения из него в юникод, закодировать их в UTF8, записать их (кроме аргумента `hash`) в алфавитном порядке в строку и вычислить из неё HMAC-SHA-256 хэш, чтоб сравнить с присланным.